# caret package createDataPartition function function of square brackets

Tags: r-caret

what is the function of [[1]] in below command?

Train <- createDataPartition(dataset$Class, p = .8)[[1]]

Train1 <- dataset[ Train, ]

Answer (score 1):

found answer after a lot of tryiing...posting it as it might be useful to others

answer:
by default creatDataPartition returns LIST datatype. we want Train to store row numbers or Integer data...thats why we have to put [[1]]...because of [[1]], Train has only Integer data. Therefore the next statement Train1 <- dataset works...

instead of doing this we can also modify statement 1 as Train <- createDataPartition(dataset$Class, p = .8, list=FALSE) and the second statement will work...

to understand difference between [] and [[]], you can run observecode

> j<-list(na="J", weight=55000)
>
> class(j[1])

[1] "list"

> class(j[[1]])

[1] "character"

> class(j[1:2])

[1] "list"

> class(j[[1:2]])

Error in j[[1:2]] : subscript out of bounds